# Dual Boot Ubuntu on Windows 7 not working

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I just recently downloaded ubuntu linux, and then burned it to a dvd. I just installed it, and not when I go to boot it, it auto boots windows 7, and doesn't give me an option to dual boot it. What is wrong?

I have:

- Windows 7
- Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit
- Toshiba Satellite
- Installed via dvd

Why does it not give me the option for dual boot?

Comment: Have you tried using `Boot-repair`?

Comment: What is that? And how do I get it?

Comment: have a Look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Have a look at the solution try it and tell us what happens!

Comment: @Nullpointer I'll try that. I'll be back in a little.

Comment: @Whoever-Down-Voted-Me Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: @user3204773 judging by the questions in the posted answer (which should have been asked as comments under the question), your question seems to need more clarity and debugging details.  Maybe this is the reason for downvoting.  It is not enough to ask a legitimate/on-topic question, it must be sufficiently clear in order to receive confidently resolving answers and help future researchers to know if their situation resembles your situation.  [Edit]ing your question would be one way to potentially prevent downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

@user3204773

There are many good tutorials on dual booting Ubuntu along side windows. I recently configure a Toshiba Satellite with the aid of below mentioned referances. Also can you tell us what you have done so far.

- How did you create the partitions?
- What are the bios settings?

  Below are few good reference that might help you.

References

- [Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu-12-10 in uefi mode Install Ubuntu](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
- [Linux alongside windows Installing](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
- [Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)